# compare two columns and prints the 2nd column in 2nd file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I Need to compare 1st two columns of two files, if the results are equal need to print the 2nd column of  1st file into 2nd file for all the matches in 1st file.

Inputs:

```
cat sample.txt
135,135-00
135,135-13
135,135-134
235,120-23
235,190-56

cat dump_test.csv
135,121,4,VA,date,date
135,128,6,VA,date,date
135,131,9,VA,date,date
235,128,10,date,date
```

Output File:

```
cat output.txt
135,121,4,VA,date,date,135-00
135,128,6,VA,date,date,135-00
135,131,9,VA,date,date,135-00
135,121,4,VA,date,date,135-13
135,128,6,VA,date,date,135-13
135,131,9,VA,date,date,135-13
135,121,4,VA,date,date,135-134
135,128,6,VA,date,date,135-134
135,131,9,VA,date,date,135-134
235,128,10,date,date,120-23
235,128,10,date,date,190-56
```

Comment: Simple two-passes Python program. First pass check for match, seocond pass to generate the desired output. Using Python's string.split(line, ",").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{i=0}FNR==NR{first[i]=$0; i=i+1;}NR!=FNR{for(j=0;j<i;j++){split(first[j],line); if(line[1]==$1) print $0,line[2]}}' sample.txt dump_test.csv

135,121,4,VA,date,date 135-00
135,121,4,VA,date,date 135-13
135,121,4,VA,date,date 135-134
135,128,6,VA,date,date 135-00
135,128,6,VA,date,date 135-13
135,128,6,VA,date,date 135-134
135,131,9,VA,date,date 135-00
135,131,9,VA,date,date 135-13
135,131,9,VA,date,date 135-134
235,128,10,date,date 120-23
235,128,10,date,date 190-56
```

What it does?

In short

creates an array `first` from each line in the first file, `sample.txt`

for each line in second file `dumb_test` it checks if the first field is in first, if yes appends the second colum in first with the line and prints.

Long

`FNR==NR` ensures that the following command works only for the first file, `sample.txt`

`first` is an array, which saves each line in file one, `sample.txt` and is indexed using `i`

`first[i]=$0` copies the entire line into the array,  and increments the index `i`

`NR!=FNR` ensures that the following command is excecuted for second file `dumb_test.csv`

the `for` iterates through the array `first`, that is lines in the first file.

`split(first[j],line)` the `first[i]` into the array `line`

eg when `first[0] = 135,135-00`

`split(first[0], line)` makes `line[1] = 135` and `line[2] = 135-00`
here `line[1]` is column one and `line[2]` is column two of first file

the if checks the `line[1] == $1` that is the first column in file one `sample.txt` is equal to first colum in second file `dumb_test.csv`

if so prints the entire line in second file, `$0` appeded with the second colum of first file, line[2]

`print $0,line[2]`

Comment: @Marjer Edited. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

is this okay for you?

```
join -t',' test sample
```

output:

```
135,121,4,VA,date,date,135-00
135,121,4,VA,date,date,135-13
135,121,4,VA,date,date,135-134
135,128,6,VA,date,date,135-00
135,128,6,VA,date,date,135-13
135,128,6,VA,date,date,135-134
135,131,9,VA,date,date,135-00
135,131,9,VA,date,date,135-13
135,131,9,VA,date,date,135-134
235,128,10,date,date,120-23
235,128,10,date,date,190-56
```